# Isomorphy between Lebesgue space $L_1$ and the $l_1$ sum of $L_1[0,1]$ spaces

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that for an infinite index set $I$, we have that $L_{1}([0,1]^{I}, \mathbb{R})$ can be written as the infinite direct sum of $L_{1}([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, i.e.
$$L_{1}([0,1]^{I}, \mathbb{R})=\bigoplus_{l_{1}, I}L_{1}([0,1], \mathbb{R})?
$$
Edited in from [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413735/isomorphy-between-lebesgue-space-l1-and-the-l1-sum-of-l10-1-spaces#comment1060870_413735): Sorry if this is confusing, in this case I mean $[0, 1]$ as the compact unit interval, $I$ is an infinite set and $\bigoplus_{l_1, I}$ is the infinite $l_1$ sum over $I$.

Comment: Sorry if this confusing, in this case I mean $[0,1]$ as the compact unit interval, $I$ is an infinite set and $\bigoplus_{l_{1}, I}$ is the infinte "l-one" sum over $I$

Comment: Clarifications to the question should be part of the question, not of comments.  I have edited your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413735/isomorphy-between-lebesgue-space-l1-and-the-l1-sum-of-l10-1-spaces#comment1060870_413735) into the body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

No, if $I$ is uncountable.

Hint: The unit ball of $L_{2}([0,1]^{I})$ is a weakly compact non separable subset of $L_{1}([0,1]^{I})$, while a weakly compact subset of any $\ell_1$-sum of uncountably many copies of a space must be contained in an $\ell_1$-sum of countably many copies of the space.

If $I$ is non empty and countable, $L_{1}([0,1]^{I})$ is separable and thus is isometrically isomorphic to $L_{1}([0,1])$. This can be found in text books on real analysis, including, for example, Royden's book.